# GridView Select and delete Command conflicting at row level

Tags: asp.net, ajax, events, gridview, updatepanel

We are handling following two scenarios in gridview :

1) Attaching onclick handler in 'onRowCreated' event for firing selectIndexChanged event on row click of the grid. Code runs for each row.

```
e.Row.Attributes.Add("onClick", Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex.ToString()));
```

2) Also Setting Command name for Image Button in first cell of the grid as 'Delete' so Grid delete event fires on click of image button.

```
<ItemTemplate>
     <ImageButton ID="imbDelete" CommandName="Delete" runat="server" SkinID="DeleteButton" ToolTip="Delete" CausesValidation="false" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

All these scenarios were running fine before upgrade to .net 4.5 (also have updated ajax control toolkit), but now these two operations are conflicting and delete operation hangs when I click on delete button. After clicking delete button , select is getting fired as its part of the same row (Begin Request/End request is getting called for Select) and then(Begin request for Delete Operation is called, end request never happens). Hence, operation hangs.

- This only happens when solution is deployed on IIS. Works fine on ASP.NET Development Server.
- Only happens with IE, all versions. In other browsers it works fine.
- Event selectedIndexChanged gets called when I just click on row. But when clicking on delete button which is in a cell of row , the operation hangs and no event is called.

I have been going crazy because of this issue, any help is appreciated.
Update: Still stuck, any idea guys ?

Gaurav Tarey

Comment: Could this be related to the framework taking over when it sees certain keywords, like 'delete' being used. Maybe give it a go using your own variant of the word so you know what it means but the framework ignores it?

Comment: @FullTimeSkeleton, I also tried using my own keyword and then using RowCommand event to handle it , but same result :( .

Comment: Are you using a OnRowCommand to catch the delete or an onClick?

Comment: When we use 'delete' keyword as command name and specify a OnRowDeleting event in grid, then .net automatically looks for this event when the button is clicked. If the name is something else you can check for it in OnRowCommand. I have tried both and none of it works.

Comment: The OnClick is specified in the code to attach SelectedIndexChanged to the click of a row. Which it does successfully.

Comment: Don't suppose you've got AllowCustomPaging = true on your gridview do you? I recall seeing this as an issue that can affect newly transferred 4.5 projects. Weird but it might be it.

Comment: Yeah I read about it too, that had something to do with certain handlers (axd mainly) not loading on IIS (they internally do on development server). Paging is not allowed on grids in this case though.

Comment: And as I said it works fine in firefox and chrome. So I suppose its nothing to do with missing handlers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just used different event instead of onClick, this is just a workaround and not a proper solution. Microsoft should just stop making IE.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just observe & share error console of the browser (not sure about IE) try firefox and capture it..

I think F12 >> script>>Console should work in IE as well

Comment: There is nothing in error console, only timeout message comes after set time. :(